# PlantUML: multiple note right in sequence overlap

Tags: plantuml

I have this sequence of `note right` in a PlantUML sequence diagram:

```
note right #ee00aa: refactor
note right #ff0000: bug
```

Instead of showing the notes below each other, they overlap:

[image]

Is there a way to show them not overlapping?

Comment: Maybe best to submit an issue in the plantuml issue tracker http://forum.plantuml.net/ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick test and maybe the following does work for you / gives some pointers:

```
@startuml
Bob -> Alice : hello
note right of Alice #ee00aa: refactor
note right of Alice #ff0000:  bug
@enduml
```

[image]